# How to plot the slope field of the differential equation y'=y-x² in Mathematica with VectorPlot?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I'm new into Wolfram Mathematica and I'm despairing of plottin a slope field in Mathematica.
The differential equation is `y'=y-x²` and I want to plot its slope field in the area of `|x| <= 3, -1 <= y <= 4`, scaling the length of the slope field to 1. 
I found out that I can do this with the `VectorPlot` function, but I cannot get it done by my own. Can someone show me how to do this?

Edit: Is this correct: `VectorPlot[{1, y[x] - x^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y[x], -1, 4}]` ?

Comment: `VectorPoints` is not a function, its an option to `VectorPlot` that doesnt seem to have anything to do with your question. Maybe want to ask on mathematica.stackexchange.com in any case.

Comment: You are right, this was a mistake of mine. I meant 'VectorPlot'.

Comment: that would be syntactically correct if you used `y` instead of `y[x]` (both places).  Its not entirely clear why you want the vector plot a scalar.

Comment: Because i want to do this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope_field . Man i just recognized that there is an example for the VectorPlot function in this article...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
VectorPlot[{1, y - x^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -1, 4},
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True, StreamPoints -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: Ok I have to admit that this looks much nicer. Thank you for that.